# Bash trace mode (bash -x) in the shebang

Tags: bash

How come this style works:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
#...
```

But this doesn't?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash -x
#...
```

It gives me a not found error. Trace mode needs to be set later as `set -x`?

Please note that I can use `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The shebang-line mechanism only parses the first space and passes the rest of the line as one single argument to the executable, so writing

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash -x
```

is like calling

```
$ /usr/bin/env "bash -x"
```

on the command line.

There is no executable called `"bash -x"` (with a space in the command name), so this fails.

Comment: So can you explain why this works? `#!/bin/bash -x`?

Comment: Oh I see, there's no space in that case.

Comment: I just read that spaces are to be avoided in the argument "for compatibility reasons", so maybe other systems interpret the spaces differently (i. e. honor them and split further arguments).  So you should not rely on the mechanism I state above, it just is one implementation which seems to be the widest-spread as of today.

Answer (score 9):

You can always use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x
```